# Passing a list through Python to C++

Tags: python, c++, subprocess

So I have a Python program that's finding .txt file directories and then passing those directories as a list(I believe) to my C++ program. The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to pass the list to C++ properly. I have used :

```
subprocess.call(["path for C++ executable"] + file_list)
```

where `file_list` is the `[]` of txt file directories.

My arguments that my C++ code accepts are:

```
 int main (int argc, string argv[])
```

Is this correct or should I be using a vector? When I do use this as my argument and try to print out the list I get the directory of my executable, the list, and then smiley faces, symbols, and then the program crashes.

Any suggestions? My main point that I am trying to find out is the proper syntax of utilizing subprocess.call. Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Thanks for helping edit stuff Ashoka... This is my first post ever.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question about passing the list - however, an alternative option if you can't get it working would be to write the file paths into a temp file, and then pass the temp file's path to your C++ program as a string.

Comment: That is a pretty easy fix, but I am trying to keep it more contained so I don't have text files floating around... Is there a way to delete that temp file in python after I am done utilizing it in python?

Comment: I don't know about using `subprocess.call` (which is your question), but I found that using `cython` for something like this is fairly simple.

Comment: You should be able to delete it in either your `Python` script or `C++` program, just look up the command, should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Part of the question would be how many files do you plan on being sent to this application? You have to also keep command line command length in mind. Also does this need to work in a `Windows` environment and what if the filename path has a space in it? How would you account for this potential space which may make 1 file path look like 2 different file paths?

Comment: around 150 files, in windows envr, and I need the space to be in between each directory because I am utilizing each one on a separate basis through my C++ program

Comment: Shouldn't it be `int main (int argc, char * argv[])`?

Comment: I am glad you brought that up. This is part of my question as well. If I am passing in a list how does that equate with a list in python? Is it just a pointer or should it be a string[]? If I use the string I actually can see an output, if it is a char * argv[] then I cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post this alternative solution since it would also work for other long lists of strings that needed to be passed.

In your `Python` script create a text file (I'll call it "masterFile") and write the file paths to the masterFile.  You could give each file path a separate line.  Then pass the masterFile's file path to your `C++` program.  This way you don't have to worry about the length of your command line arguments.  Let your `C++` program open and read the file for processing.

You can use something like `os.remove()` to get rid of the masterFile in your `Python` script once the `C++` program has finished.

Also, you mentioned in the comments that you need to do different tasks dependent on different file paths:  A suggestion would be to add a char at the beginning of each line in the masterFile to signal what needs to be done for the particular file.  Example:

```
a Random/path/aFile.txt # a could mean do task 1
b Random2/path2/differentFile.c # b could mean do task 2
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that is what I will end up doing. (Seems to be less of a headache) I appreciate you taking the time to answer this. Also, I can't vote up your answer because I am five reputation away... If you could upvote mine I could upvote yours heh.

Comment: @jnorris4118 In that case you should mark Andrew's answer as correct so that this question is "resolved".

Comment: Sorry... just found out... heh

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use `cython`, (not a direct answer). Here is a simple complete example:

Suppose you have the following files:

cython_file.cpp
python_file.py
setup.py
sum_my_vector.cpp
sum_my_vector.h

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension(
    name="cython_file", 
    sources=["cython_file.pyx", "sum_my_vector.cpp"],
    extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"], 
    language="c++",
    )]

setup(
    name = 'cython_file',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    )
```

**cython_file.pyx**

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "sum_my_vector.h":
    int sum_my_vector(vector[int] my_vector)

def sum_my_vector_cpp(my_list):
    cdef vector[int] my_vector = my_list
    return sum_my_vector(my_vector)
```

**sum_my_vector.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "sum_my_vector.h"

using namespace::std;

int sum_my_vector(vector<int> my_vector)
{
  int my_sum = 0;
  for (auto iv = my_vector.begin(); iv != my_vector.end(); iv++)       
      my_sum += *iv;

  return my_sum;
}
```

**sum_my_vector.h**

```
#ifndef SUM_MY_VECTOR
#define SUM_MY_VECTOR

using namespace::std;

int sum_my_vector(vector<int> my_vector);

#endif
```

**python_file.py**

```
from cython_file import sum_my_vector_cpp

print sum_my_vector_cpp([1,2,3,5])
```

Now run

`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

and the you can run the python file

```
python python_file.py
11
```

Answer (score 3):

> *"Passing a list through Python to C++"*

An alternative approach would be to use [*`Boost.Python`*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/), this may not answer your question directly, but still its worth pointing out another solution.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void get_dir_list( boost::python::list dir_list )
{

    for (int i = 0; i < len(dir_list); ++i)
    {

        std::string x = boost::python::extract<std::string>(dir_list[i]);
        // perform stuffs
        std::cout << "This is " << x << std::endl ;
    }
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(get_dir_list)
{
    def("get_dir_list", get_dir_list);
}
```

<sup>Compiled Using :
*`g++ main.cpp -shared -fPIC -o get_dir_list.so -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lboost_python`*</sup>

---

Usage :

```
import get_dir_list
import os
get_dir_list.get_dir_list(os.listdir('.'))
```

<kbd>[***`Live Demo Here`***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/853f14f9d3e73641)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You pass a list to `subprocess.call`. `subprocess.call` converts this to what is needed for the system (which may vary, but certainly isn't a Python list).  The system then arranges for this to be copied somewhere in the new process, and sets up the standard arguments to `main`, which are `int, char**`.  In your C++ program, you must define `main` as `int main( int argc, char** argv )`; nothing else will work.  (At least... a system could support `int main( std::string const& )` or some such as an extension.  But I've never heard of one that did.)